# Missing Device Options next to run button in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I am missing whatever the thing is called that is a drop down menu allowing one to select between devices and simulators to build and run onto.  I have had trouble searching for a solution because I don't know what this thing is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your display is not wide enough. (maybe the name of your target or device is too long?).

You can select the target and device like this, too:

[image]

Comment: I have xcode fully expanded on a 2015 macbook w/ retina and the destination names are basically the same as yours.  worth noting is that there is the double arrow on the right side of the top panel indicating there is more content (as if it isn't able to fit) but when i click it it simply displays a  greyed out "scheme".

Comment: hmm.. I have no idea, why it disappeared. Sorry. :-/ But I hope, I cloud help you a bit with the workaround